A key sequence that automatically presses keys like enter, *after* a command that requires manually typing a letter?
For instance, I want to move to the window in the top left, and move to a line using :HopVertical (which is n-mapped to j for me) with hop.nvim*, type in a character manually (I want to type it manually), then press a key like enter automatically. I tried this keymap but it doesn't work.

wincmd t, j, manually typed character, <cr> (or enter pressed automatically).
vim.keymap.set({"n", "v"}, ";", "<cmd>wincmd t<cr>j<cr>", opts)

(I want to use this with vuffers.nvim in the top left corner, as well as other key sequences).
* show one letter hint on each line, press the hint


I would try:
vim.keymap.set({"n", "v"}, ";", [["<C-w>tj"..(feedkeys(nr2char(getchar()).."<CR>")?"":"")]], {expr=true})

Where:

feedkeys()?"":"" is a way to call feedkeys() and ignoring the return value
nr2char(getchar()) wait that the user hit a keystroke and convert the keystroke into a character
nr2char(getchar()).."<CR>" append <CR> to the input keystroke


I want the enter key to be pressed automatically after doing :HopVertical and entering in a key manually. I put the keymap in code formatting to show all the characters.
